# Right way to use transition "above all"

Tags: grammaticality, word-usage

I want to emphasize a question from a poll in my project thesis for university. 
However, I´m not certain with the usage of "above all" in the following example.

> Last but not least, the participants were asked [*question and result here*]. 
>   **Above all,** this question displays the necessity to implement [...].

There were some questions before as you might have noticed (*Last but not least*), but I want to highlight that this question shows the consequence - to implement something - better than any other question.

Comment: If you are going to talk about other consequences from the same question after this sentence, may I suggest "first and foremost"? "Above all else" is slightly more appropriate than "above all."

Comment: Nice suggestion, I´m going to keep that in mind for some other occasions. Nonetheless, in this case the only consequence is to implement something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Above all" doesn't mean "This question displays something better than the other questions", as you seem to think.

It means "This question **displays many things, but the most important thing** that it displays is...".

So lets say, for example, that you did a study into Pokemon Go , and found out that kids were getting run over while playing it.  You might say "Above all, this study shows that there is a serious danger to children from playing this game."  You're saying that the most important issue it raises is that of the safety of children.  There might be other things in the study, but you're highlighting this one thing as being "more important than all the other things", or "above all".

Comment: I agree, thank you for clarifying. Funnily enough I thought about writing an example question about Pokemon Go.